# Getting undefined method `belongs_to' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration: Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many, belongs-to

I'm building a texting service, where there are many messages tied to a single user. I'd like for messages to be indexed to the user table via their from_number. Below is what I've done, but I keep getting a method error.

I have the following two models defined:

1) message.rb

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

2) User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :messages
end
```

The following is the migration file I'm trying to run via rake db:migrate:

```
class UsersMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :user_name
      t.string :from_number
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.string :message_body
      t.string :from_number
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :from_number, :unique => true
  end
end
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
-- belongs_to(:user)
-- belongs_to(:user)
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `belongs_to' for #<ActiveRecord::Migration:0x007ff453826f50>
```

I define the has_many and belongs_to associations in the model, but as per Section 2.1 here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

I add the "t.belongs_to :customer, index: true" line to the migration file as well.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: What version of rails are you using? Please run `rails -v` and update your answer. `belongs_to` in migrations was added in the later versions of Rails so you may be running Rails 3.

Comment: `t.belongs_to :customer, index: true` why `:customer` ?

Comment: Which version of rails were you using @philip-cortes just curious?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `t.references :user, index: true` in your migration..

Comment: `belongs_to` is just an alias of `references` so the OP would get a similar error. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L421

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `user_id` in Messages table.

Run `rake db:drop` then remove from messages migration this line.

`t.belongs_to :user, index: true`

Run in command line this:

```
rails g migration add_user_id_to_messages user_id:interger
```

and

```
rake db:migrate
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question. The `belongs_to` is in the migration and rails uses that to create the user_id for you.

Comment: @PhilipCortes just for fun, can you comment `belongs_to :user` line and restart server lets see, still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

the `belongs_to` syntax for migrations was added in Rails 4. Is it possible you're using an earlier version?

In any case, you can simply add the column and index yourself:

`t.integer :user_id, index: true`